# Can I use two interceptors on same spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I have a Spring Boot application that contains two different dashboards, and so each user can access only one. Actually I have one interceptor that secure one dashboard, but the second dashboard needs another interceptor. This is possible?

This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new AutorizadorInterceptorEscola());
    }
}
```

I need to add another interceptor to secure the second dashboard.

Comment: Why not to just call `registry.addInterceptor()` twice?

Comment: it would have taken a few minutes to just try it. What might lead us to believe it's possible? The name of the method is `addInterceptors`, which is plural, and they're being added to an interceptor registry, which would lead one to believe it's possible. Even if it *wasn't* documented in the Spring Boot reference that in turn points to the Spring MVC doc--two clicks gets you to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Configuration Class extends with WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
     registry.addInterceptor(new GuestInterceptor());
     registry.addInterceptor(new AdminInterceptor());
}
```